How can I import svg code from javascript module?
I'm trying to import an svg in Vanilla ES6 / ES7 to use with mo.js like in this example https://mojs.github.io/tutorials/shape-swirl/#custom-shapes.

I've tried to put the code in a javascript module and import it without success because it gave an error in console:
const charIcon = () => {
    const icon = `<svg id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 350.56 219.62">
      <defs>
        <style>
          .cls-1 {
            fill: #f07458;
          }
    
          .cls-1, .cls-2 {
            stroke-width: 0px;
          }
    
          .cls-2 {
            fill: #000;
          }
    
          .cls-3 {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
          }
    
          .cls-3, .cls-4 {
            stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            stroke-width: .25px;
          }
    
          .cls-4 {
            fill: #f0ba58;
            stroke: #f0ba58;
          }
        </style>
      </defs>
      <g id="Layer_7" data-name="Layer 7">
        <g>
          <path class="cls-1" d="M292.52,160.38l-92.97,51.97-128.85-46.88s25.7-16.34,36.15-21.43c10.46-5.09,22.24-14.47,26.53-20.63,4.28-6.16,8.37-5.48,8.37-5.48-3.31-6.79-6.49-23.72-6.49-23.72,0,0-3.87-23.08-5.23-29.86-.44-2.17-2.08-3.79-2.08-3.79C121.08,29.32,136.79,1.9,166.87.24c36.99-2.04,50.97,23.04,51.77,36.96.3,5.15-.91,20.13-.91,20.13,0,0,2.04-1.92,3.2-2.2,4.29-1.08.31,34.91-7.9,37.3,0,0-.81,14.42-2.39,20.57,7.4-.06,14.75,13.19,25.45,16.2,8.35,2.36,34.18,19.13,36.58,19.13s19.84,12.05,19.84,12.05Z"/>
          <path class="cls-3" d="M292.52,160.38l-92.97,51.97-128.85-46.88s25.7-16.34,36.15-21.43c10.46-5.09,22.24-14.47,26.53-20.63,4.28-6.16,8.37-5.48,8.37-5.48-3.31-6.79-6.49-23.72-6.49-23.72,0,0-3.87-23.08-5.23-29.86-.44-2.17-2.08-3.79-2.08-3.79C121.08,29.32,136.79,1.9,166.87.24c36.99-2.04,50.97,23.04,51.77,36.96.3,5.15-.91,20.13-.91,20.13,0,0,2.04-1.92,3.2-2.2,4.29-1.08.31,34.91-7.9,37.3,0,0-.81,14.42-2.39,20.57,7.4-.06,14.75,13.19,25.45,16.2,8.35,2.36,34.18,19.13,36.58,19.13s19.84,12.05,19.84,12.05Z"/>
          <path class="cls-4" d="M236.09,129.2c-10.7-3.01-18.05-16.26-25.45-16.21,1.58-6.14,2.39-20.57,2.39-20.57,8.21-2.38,12.19-38.37,7.9-37.3-1.16.29-3.19,2.21-3.19,2.21,0,0,1.2-14.99.9-20.13-.76-13.14-13.24-36.17-45.68-37.05l1.38,129.03,1.75,20.21-3.13,53.29,26.59,9.67,92.96-51.97s-17.41-12.06-19.83-12.06-28.24-16.77-36.59-19.13Z"/>
          <path class="cls-3" d="M166.87.31c36.95-2.04,50.92,23.01,51.71,36.92.3,5.14-.9,20.11-.9,20.11"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M174.21,131.43c4.55,0,6.24-3.82,5.17-5.8-1.43-2.67-2.48-3.29-2.78-4.61-.6-2.58-2.7-20.56-.12-22.35,0,0,22.55-4.57,27.51-13.7,0,0-11.87,2.03-16.68,0,0,0,16.68-18.65,16.68-49.84,0,0-4.64-35.21-31.86-35-27.22.22-30.18,35.84-30.18,35.84,0,0-1.4,30.95,14,45.26,0,0-4.2-1.24-5.91-2.33s9.49,11.14,9.49,11.14c0,0-11.67-7.72-13.69-10.37,1.24,9.33,19.75,17.73,22.24,21s4.82,19.44,3.89,20.69-1.47,2.73-2.06,5.14c-1.03,4.21,4.29,4.93,4.29,4.93Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M204.8,90.04s-2.8,23.23-9.18,32.41c-6.38,9.18-5.87,9.82-8.4,9.82s-7.3,2.93-11.69,2.93-14.17-3.36-15.89-6.05c-4.17-6.54-6.51-15.5-8.79-17.45s-5.54-5.25-6.68-8.82c-1.14-3.57,0-6.82,0-6.82,0,0,9.1,6.66,13.48,7.15s2.97,3.45,2.75,5.4c-.32,2.84,3.42,2.56,3.26,6.62-.07,1.7,2.29,3.51,2.45,5.63.23,2.95-.63,6,.79,7.52,2.44,2.6,1.57,4.31,7.91,3.83,4.58-.35,7.83-2.45,7.98-5.49.06-1.17-1.49-.75-1.96-1.52-2.03-3.38-2.75-9.53-2.91-14.89-.16-5.36-.62-8.55,1.01-10.01s7.73.11,14.67-1.53c4.35-2.91,11.19-8.7,11.19-8.7Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M174.26,138.68c1.31.05,2.46.15,6.07.06-1.55,1.08-1.99,2.79-3.22,2.96-.8.11-4.25-.02-5.11-.44-1-.48-2.78-2.82-3.71-3.23,1.87.38,4.58.6,5.97.65Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M174.17,135.59c2.92.1,3.8.95,12.5-1.08-3.45,2.15-4.89,4.2-7.64,4.54-1.78.22-9.47-.05-11.39-.88-2.22-.97-3.57-3.06-5.64-3.88,4.17.76,9.06,1.2,12.16,1.3Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M216.17,66.47c3.2-2.35,5.56-8.16,4.76-11.34l-3.19,2.21s.35,2.19-.5,4.97-1.07,4.16-1.07,4.16Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M216.17,74.95s1.06-4.96,2.46-6.15,1.36,0,1.36,0c0,0-.51,6.05-1.9,7.21s-1.91-1.06-1.91-1.06Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M151.73,93.85c4.38.91,11.24,6.19,11.24,6.19,0,0-4.53.76-7.1,0s-7.15-7.11-7.15-7.11l3.01.92Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M190.12,96.54c2.91-1.11,6.8-1.96,6.8-1.96,0,0-1.92,3.15-3.97,3.79s-4.15.27-6.27.34c0,0,.53-1.05,3.44-2.16Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M70.7,165.48s25.7-16.34,36.15-21.43,22.24-14.47,26.52-20.63,8.36-5.48,8.36-5.48c8.09,10.59,17.51,22.58,32.5,24.16,8.95.94,18.15,2.17,25.97-7.8,8.77-2.4,7.67-5.91,10.74-17.8,5.55-.04,16.44,7.98,15.5,22.87,5.53-1.53,4.08-8.67,6.75-7.92,2.09.59,7.21,3.71,8.75,8.38,1.07-4.67,28.92,8.52,30.73,8.52,2.41,0,19.83,12.06,19.83,12.06l58.05,59.24H0l70.7-54.15Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M135.25,94.21s-.02-.02-.06-.03c-4.57-2.62-11.55-32.79-10.66-34.26.83-1.34,2.97.28,3.36.59l.06.05s1.64,1.62,2.08,3.79c1.36,6.77,5.23,29.86,5.23,29.86Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M162.97,100.04s-13.03-9.02-15.66-9.2-3.92,0-3.92,0c0,0,3.55,1.23,5.32,1.7s5.88,2.86,7.61,3.8c1.63.88,6.65,3.7,6.65,3.7Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M199.39,92.97s-2.32-.12-4.14.42-5.07,2.31-5.61,2.51-2.3,1.46-2.97,2.8c0,0,6.7-2.92,8.28-3.66s4.44-2.08,4.44-2.08Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M200.21,134.29s5.64-5.31,11.29-35.58c-2.36,25.56-6.14,35.58-6.14,35.58h-5.15Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M179.12,143.74s13.12-4.5,20.27-12.31c0,0-12.53,15.36-16.2,15.6s-4.07-3.29-4.07-3.29Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M177.94,110.28c-.16-5.36.11-8.94,1.73-10.4,2.89-2.32,7.01.5,13.94-1.14"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>`;
    return icon;
}
export default charIcon;


Now I'm trying to import it using https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-inline-loader.
let charIcon = require('../images/content/logo-char.svg');
console.log(charIcon);
class Char extends mojs.CustomShape {
    getShape() { return charIcon; }
}

mojs.addShape('char', Char); // passing name and Bubble class
// now it is avaliable on mojs.Shape constructor as usual
const logoChar = new mojs.Shape({
    parent: '#logoChar',
    shape: 'char',
    scale: { 0: 1 },
});

When I console log it doesn't return the code of the svg but instead returns a base64:

How can I import the svg code from a javascript module like in the first in example or import the code from a svg file? I'd prefer the first method by importing a module in order to be able to see the code and change if needed.
Hope the issue is clear.
Thank you!

But the base64 is the code of the svg isn't it? You could always base64 decode it.

The svg isn't base64. I tried to set the svg file with only one path and it stills returns base64 in the console.

Sure looks like it is to me. Of course you've pasted it as an image rather than text and there's only so much I can be bothered to retype and base64 decode.

Sorry, should I replace images with text now?

I think I need to rethink the way I'm implementing the svg. Maybe use an innerHtml and then manipulate it with GSAP.

Isn't it just async fetch and then do the mojs stuff from the onload method

From the image of the docs getShape is a method that when invoked returns a string.  However in your implementation getShape is returning a function.  Maybe change getShape() { return charIcon; } to getShape() { return charIcon(); }

Export charIcon as a string instead of a function
export const charIcon = `<svg ...>...</svg>`;

then import it either like this:
<script type=module>
import { charIcon } from '../images/content/icon.js';

// ...
</script>

or by using dynamic import:
(async () => {
  const { charIcon } = await import('../images/content/icon.js');
  // ...
})();

Alternatively you can just fetch the svg file and grab its content:
(async () => {
  const charIcon = await fetch('../images/content/icon.svg').then(res => res.text());
  // ...
})();

